# Unusuall activity

Tags: boot, 18.04, malware

I'm a new user as you can see, so sorry if the question is boring or imprecise.

I upgraded my Ubuntu 16.04 to 18.04 and everything was fine. But after a power outage, something went wrong. It did not boot correctly once or twice, after that when I boot my laptop an almost black screen stays for a couple of minutes or the ubuntu pre-screen blinks for several times and all these repeats until now. It finally works but it becomes slow and I see a "*^[[19~*" or "~" sentence repeated in many command lines. when it is booting and I press escape or in the terminal.
[when I use a terminal, sometimes someone types this repeatedly!](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vi8A1.png)
[there is nothing in the update window, although the size of update files is more than 300 mb](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NNwGc.png)

Or it does not show some options in programs, e.g. In the update window, there is nothing to show, or when I want to save a document or picture, there is not anything for the file extension. 
I have no idea what it can be. Is it a virus or can I test my OS to see if it is installed correctly? 
Because I live in Iran, some sites or repositories may be blocked and I can not update properly, so I don't know if it is installed correctly.

Comment: Maybe a power surge caused a hardware failure. Try running a live session with the USB/DVD installation media that you used to install Ubuntu.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you entered the GRUB rescue mode. You can either reinstall Ubuntu 18.04 or you can try following the steps in https://www.howtoforge.com/tutorial/repair-linux-boot-with-grub-rescue/.

If possible, please include an image of your screen so that other people could understand your problem more.